# Clean way of writing several nested if-else with number ranges in Go

Tags: go, coding-style

This piece of code is effective but I don't feel good about it when I read it. I'm finding trouble refactoring into something more legible or short. Breaking the code into several if-return doesn't seem to be of great help here. Tips? Thanks!

```
if t < 0 {
    r = 0
} else if t >= 0 && t < 7.5 {
    if m >= 0 && m < 0.125 {
        r = 1
    } else {
        r = 2
    }
} else if t >= 7.5 && t < 10 {
    if m >= 0 && m < 0.125 {
        r = 1
    } else {
        r = 4
    }
} else if t >= 10 && t < 20 {
    if m >= 0 && m < 0.125 {
        r = 1
    } else if m >= 0.125 && m < 0.25 {
        r = 3
    } else {
        r = 4
    }
} else if t >= 20 && t < 22.5 {
    if m >= 0 && m < 0.125 {
        r = 7
    } else if m >= 0.125 && m < 0.375 {
        r = 3
    } else {
        r = 4
    }
} else if t >= 22.5 && t < 27.5 {
    if m >= 0 && m < 0.125 {
        r = 7
    } else if m >= 0.125 && m < 0.625 {
        r = 5
    } else {
        r = 6
    }
} else if t >= 27.5 {
    if m >= 0 && m < 0.25 {
        r = 7
    } else if m >= 0.25 && m < 0.625 {
        r = 5
    } else {
        r = 6
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the values, you can encode the range checks with some data structures:

```
type Rng struct {
   From,To float64
   V int
}

func (r Rng) In(val float64) bool { return val>=r.From && val<r.To }

type ARange struct {
   T Rng
   M []Rng  
   Def int // Default value for r if none of the M ranges match
}

var ranges=[]ARange{ {T:Rng{0,7.5}, M:[]Rng{ {0,0.125,1} }, Def: 2 },
  ...
```

Then, write a for-loop that goes through each element of `ranges` and checks `t` and `m` to see if there are any matches.

Comment: Thank you, you put in code what I was starting to think. Love this, short and readable.

Comment: func (r Rng) In(val float64) { return val>=r.From && val<r.To } I think it's missing a bool as return value. Would be: func (r Rng) In(val float64) bool { return val>=r.From && val<r.To }

Comment: Yes, I fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

Simplify the outer if / else if / else removing redundant comparisons and converting to switch:

```
switch {
case t < 0:
    r = 0
case t < 7.5:
    if m >= 0 && m < 0.125 {
        r = 1
    } else {
        r = 2
    }
case t < 10:
    if m >= 0 && m < 0.125 {
        r = 1
    } else {
        r = 4
    }
case t < 20:
    if m >= 0 && m < 0.125 {
        r = 1
    } else if m >= 0.125 && m < 0.25 {
        r = 3
    } else {
        r = 4
    }
case t < 22.5:
    if m >= 0 && m < 0.125 {
        r = 7
    } else if m >= 0.125 && m < 0.375 {
        r = 3
    } else {
        r = 4
    }
case t < 27.5:
    if m >= 0 && m < 0.125 {
        r = 7
    } else if m >= 0.125 && m < 0.625 {
        r = 5
    } else {
        r = 6
    }
default:
    if m >= 0 && m < 0.25 {
        r = 7
    } else if m >= 0.25 && m < 0.625 {
        r = 5
    } else {
        r = 6
    }
}
```

Similar modifications are possible on the inner statements. The code:

```
    if m >= 0 && m < 0.125 {
        r = 1
    } else {
        r = 2
    }
```

becomes:

```
   switch {
   case m < 0:
       // r not changed
   case m < 0.125:
       r = 1
   default:
       r = 2
   }
```

Comment: Good stuff! It's a good simplification and easier to do vs the chosen answer. Did not select this because it still keeps the line count pretty high, but will keep it in my tricks bag.